# Getting Sentiment Scores from Watson Discovery News

Tags: watson-discovery

I am passing the query to `DiscoveryV1` API as "query":

```
"\"WTI OIL FUTURES\"",

    "aggregations": [
    "term(host).term(enriched_text.sentiment.document.label)",
    "term(enriched_text.sentiment.document.label)"
```

This returns a JSON which is large. I would like to just pick the sentiment score as shown in the Watson demo page. In the demo page the JSON output is brief, but the same JSON output is not obtained when I use the API (`DiscoveryV1`) through python. Could someone help?

Answer (score 0):

There are two quite different things you could try here.

Often, when I'm doing an interesting aggregation, all I want to get back is the results of the aggregation; I'm not actually interesting in seeing the documents that match the base query. This can be achieved with: `count=0`.

If you do want some documents to be returned, you can limit what fields are returned for each document with the `return` option. To just get the title and url of the news item, you can use this: `return=title,url`

Comment: If I use the above query in python I dont get the same out put as shown in the web page. The JSON from the web page is easy to analyse for sentiment scores. It gives something like this, {
  "sentiment": {
    "type": "term",
    "field": "enriched_text.sentiment.document.label",
    "results": [
      {
        "key": "positive",
        "matching_results": 31205
      },
      {
        "key": "negative",
        "matching_results": 9600
      },
      {
        "key": "neutral",
        "matching_results": 1124

Comment: How would I get just numerical values for the sentiment score?

Comment: qopts = {
  "query": "\"WTI OIL FUTURES\"",
  "filter": "language:(english|en),crawl_date>2017-08-10T12:00:00+0530,crawl_date<2017-10-10T12:00:00+0530",
  "aggregations": [
    "term(host).term(enriched_title.sentiment.document.label)",
    "term(enriched_title.sentiment.document.label)"
  ],
   'return':'enriched_title.sentiment.document.label',}
I am getting 67 records but my tally of positive , negative , and neutral doesn't match the reported one from the demo page. Is there any rule which is applied to calculate the sentiment score?